# P4 Python error: file(s) not on client

Tags: python, perforce

I am using the p4 Python module to try and open several files for edit.  Basically I have a list of files that I am grabbing from a txt document.  I then do some formatting to each item in the list and append those items to an empty list.  My method is not the most efficient but I am just trying to get this to work before optimizing.

```
edit_files = []

with open('C:\\Users\\rgriffin\Desktop\\replace.txt', 'r' )as f:
    for line in f:
        l = line.partition(',')[0]
        e = l.replace('#(', '')
        r = e.replace('U:\\', '//Stream/main/')
        q= r.replace('\\', '/')
        edit_files.append(q)
f.close

for i in edit_files:
    p4.run("edit" , i)
```

With this code I get an error:

> [Warning]: '"//Stream/main/Data/anims/stuff/char/Emotion_Angry.hkx" - file(s) not on client.'

If I change the last line to this...

```
p4.run("edit" , "//Stream/main/Data/anims/stuff/char/Emotion_Angry.hkx")
```

The file is checked out as expected.  I did a type check and `i` is a string.

Input data:

```
#("U:\Data\anims\stuff\char\Emotion_Angry_Partial.hkx", "u:\Assets\Actors\stuff\char\Animation\char_Idle.max")
```

Comment: Did you tried print i ?
what is the input txt document format ?

Comment: Seems like quotes(") are there in your in your query. Try running 
    p4.run("edit" , i.replace('"',''))

Comment: print(i) results in "//Stream/main/Data/anims/stuff/car/Emotion_Angry.hkx"
My text document is plain text.
p4.run("edit" , i.replace('"','')) results in
  File "F:\replaceFile.py", line 27, in <module>
    p4.run("edit" , i.replace('"','')) 
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\P4.py", line 533, in run
    result = P4API.P4Adapter.run(self, *self.__flatten(args))
P4.P4Exception: [P4#run] Warnings during command execution( "p4 edit 
" )

 [Warning]: '\n - file(s) not on client.'

Comment: there you go. You have extra quotes. Use : p4.run("edit" , i.replace('"',''))

Comment: I am not sure if the document type would effect this as I am creating a string and appending it to the edit_files list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following command, there are quote characters at ends. Do remove them. Also seems like there are empty lines.
Change

```
for i in edit_files:
    p4.run("edit" , i)
```

to

```
for i in edit_files:
    f=i.replace('"','').strip()
    if len(f)>0:
      print "Opening  ["+f+"]"
      p4.run("edit" , f)
```

or One liner

```
[p4.run("edit" , i.replace('"','').strip()) for i in edit_files if i.strip()]
```

Or you may want to change your populating code itself:
Use:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\rgriffin\Desktop\\replace.txt', 'r' )as f:
    for line in f:
        l = line.partition(',')[0].replace('#(', '').replace('U:\\', '//Stream/main/').replace('\\', '/').replace('"', '').strip()
        if len(l)>0:
            edit_files.append(l)
f.close
```

Comment: Perfect thanks!  On little edit.
    for i in edit_files:
        f=i.replace('"','').strip()
        print (f)

        if len(f)>0:
          print ("Opening  ["+f+"]")
          p4.run("edit" , f)